# Can I get rid of the "Marked as Final" strip in an Office document?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010, powerpoint-2007

When a user opens a document (or in my case, presentation) that has been marked as final, a yellow strip appears at the top of the window explaining that the document has been marked as final and that editing is disabled. The strip also includes an "Edit Anyway" button.

I'd like to programmatically close this strip. Is that possible?

NOTE: I'm not doing this to try to prevent changes; I know that the user can still remove the mark-as-final setting. I just want rid of the big yellow bar.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do:

```
oPres.Final = False 
' where oPres is a reference to the 
' presentation you want to change
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do want the presentation to be "final" (with changes disabled). I just want rid of the yellow bar.

Comment: There might be some WinAPI way of dismissing that window, but I don't see any way of doing it in VBA.